# CaaS- Is it possible to trace the URL invoked after a voice call?

Tags: cloud, telephony, telecommunication

First of all, sorry if it's a stupid or off-topic question. This question is about CaaS (communication as a service/cloud telephony). As I asked I want to know if it is possible to trace or monitor the URL(s) invoked in a voice call? To be clear, here is an example:

1. You made a voice call to a phone number that has IVRS (Interactive Voice Response System).
2. The IVR says **Please enter your ticket number after the tone to check status of your ticket**
3. You enter your ticket number (as a DTMF), for example: 64788489.
4. Their cloud telephony system makes a HTTP GET call to following URL (for an instance):
   http://example.com/CheckTicketStatus?TicketNumber=64788489
5. The cloud telephony system gets response as: `{"ticket":64788489, "status":"ticket is resolved and closed" }`
6. The IVR finally says **Your ticket number 64788489 has been resolved and closed**

In above example's point #4, a HTTP call was made to check the ticket status. So can I detect/trace/monitor such HTTP calls by anyway or by any tool?